# Navigation Timing API. What's going on between domContentLoadedEventStart and domContentLoadedEventEnd?

Tags: javascript, dom

W3C specifies a list of event and their corresponding timings that user agents must return if they want to support the [Navigation Timing API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/NavigationTiming/Overview.html).

A list you can see here: http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#process

Understanding which process relates to which events is pretty straight forward in most cases. But one thing that eludes me is what is going on between `domContentLoadedEventStart` and `domContentLoadedEventEnd`.

Here is what I have understood so far and base my reflections on:

1. `domLoading` // The UA starts parsing the document.
2. `domInteractive` // The UA has finished parsing the document. Users
   can interact with the page.
3. `domContentLoaded` // The document has been completely loaded and
   parsed and deferred scripts, if any, have executed. (Async scripts,
   if any, might or might not have executed???)
4. `domComplete` // The DOM Tree is completely built. Async scripts, if
   any, have executed.
5. `loadEventEnd` // The UA has a fully completed page. All resources,
   like images, swf, etc, have loaded.

One should be able to deduce what happens after phase #3 (`domContentLoaded`) by understanding what triggered event #4 (`domComplete`) but did not trigger previous events.

So one would think that “Async scripts, if any, have executed” means that asynchronous scripts get executed after phase #3 but before event #4. But according to my tests, this is not what happens, unless my test is wrong. (I tried to replicate my test on `JSFiddle`, but I can’t make the defered/async script work since there is no way to add attribute on external scripts.)

**So my question is: What process(es) takes place between `domContentLoadedEventStart` and `domContentLoadedEventEnd`?**

Comment: You gave a very good description of the document loading events

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those timings have to do with the `domContentLoaded` event(s).  It's similar to the `load` event with  `loadEventStart` and `loadEventEnd`.  Instead of using `load`, you use `DOMContentLoaded`.

For example, adding a `DOMContentLoaded` event and running some code in it, should give you a different start and end.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var j = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        j = i;
    }
});
```

Once that event is ran, the navigation timing API will return a different timestamp between the start and end times, depending on how long your event(s) take to run.

From the W3C documentation you pointed out, I believe there are no other processes going on with these timings.

> **domContentLoadedEventStart attribute**
>
> This attribute must return the time immediately before the user agent fires the DOMContentLoaded event at the Document.
>
> **domContentLoadedEventEnd attribute**
>
> This attribute must return the time immediately after the document's DOMContentLoaded event completes.

Comment: Ok, I get it. It corresponds to the period during which the browser executes the JS code callback of the DOMContentLoaded event.